# How do I retrieve and store the coordinates of a user's current location in a variable using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, coordinates, cllocationmanager

So, I am making a UIButton that, when pressed, generates an annotation (pin) at the current users location which is then stored in the app and used to notify the user when they return to this location. I am having trouble finding a way to access the lat and long coordinates of my user.

I am planning on creating a `func` that stops the location getting process and then restarts it when the button is pressed: `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation(); locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();` and then right here, the location coordinates that are located at the moment of restarting the location services should be the most accurate thus I want to generate a map annotation at those coordinates.

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW9) says that the corrdinates can be retrieved by using 
`@NSCopying var location: CLLocation! { get }` but this is (read-only) and I need a `var` I can work with.

Thanks so much!

Comment: it is a readonly property because you can get the user location but you can not modify it. If you just want to know (get) the user location, why do you need to modify the value?

Comment: Also, be aware that starting Location updates and immediately reading the location may not give a very precise location as it can take some time for the device to get an accurate fix . You are better off leaving location updates running while your app is in the foreground and then simply grabbing them`location` value when the button is pressed

Comment: @Ikanzakic: Because he wants to be teleported to that location ;-)